# Is there a way to create a small-caps character style in Pages 6?

Tags: pages, iwork, formatting

Cross-post from discussions.apple.com.

As the title says: I have a paragraph style for the main body of my document. Within a paragraph, there are some words that need to be in small caps. From my playing around, it seems as if "small caps" can be an attribute of a *paragraph* style but not a *character* style—and of course, if I set some words to a different paragraph style the entire paragraph changes, which is not what I want.

I want this to be in a character style so I can quickly enter into it with a function-key shortcut. I am aware that I can set small-caps on and off by clicking into a menu.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to make this character style possible?

Comment: On Pages 6.2 I selected some words, applied the capitalization (using the Advanced Options after the "bold, italic and underline" buttons) and even changed the color. Then in the Character Styles dropdown menu I just pressed + and added a new style with related shortcut... what is different in your experience?

Comment: Well, I don't know what I was doing that wasn't working, because I was trying to do exactly that in Pages 6.3. It was not allowing me to create a new character style when the only change was in the capitalization. I tried again and now it's working for me, exactly as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new style, you need to have some text with ONLY that style selected:
 if in the style inspector the "Characters Styles" dropdown menu shows "multiple styles" or "none" or the name of an existing style WITHOUT a trailing '*', the "new style" button will be grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

As Gio Valerio said, it works as intuitively as you'd expect—except it didn't work for me when I tried originally.

The answer is: Edit text as desired and look at the character style menu, and hope that the "new style" button isn't grayed out.